# Не получается подключение к базе данных Oracle (11g)

Tags: spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

Я использую Spring boot.

Поначалу все работало прекрасно, но внезапно проект перестал запускаться вот с такой ошибкой.

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Ошибка ввода/вывода: Got minus one
>   from a read call
>
> Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
>
> 2019-10-16 12:58:44.505  WARN 9988 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc
>   url from datasource

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//SRV01:1521/mmm_mmm
spring.datasource.username=ddd
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

Почему невозможно получить connection ?
Можно ли пояснить почему ?

**Обновление**

Как оказалось, применялись к моей учетной записи некоторые политики безопасности и поэтому на локальной машине обрывались любые попытки подключиться к удаленным хостам.

Как это именно было  - неизвестно. Но теперь проблема исчезла.